# How to refer to JavaScript packages when passing in parameters to Angular in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I wanted to make the following more like-a-bossy.

```
<div (click)="lastCall(999)">click me</div>
```

I tried to use `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` but the computer complained about it not being recognized. So the following didn't work.

```
<div (click)="lastCall(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)">click me</div>
```

I had to declare a property in my TS file like this.

```
private max: number = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

And **then** refer to it like this.

```
<div (click)="lastCall(max)">click me</div>
```

Is there a way to pass `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;` directly in the call? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you have to write

```
export class MyComponent {
  max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // type inference FTW
}
```

is that, while a template is *logically* part of a component, it is does not have access to the same lexical environment as the component class. The reason `MyComponent` has access to it is that `MyComponent` is plain old JavaScript code.

A template exists in a different environment.

This becomes clearer if use an example that does not involve a global variable.

Consider

class:

```
import {π} from 'app/constants';

export class MyComponent {
  updateArea(radius: number) {
    this.area = π * radius ** 2;
  }

  area?: number;
}
```

template:

```
<input #radius type="number">
<button (click)="updateArea(radius.value)">
<span>{{area}}</span>
```

In the above, `MyComponent.prototype.updateArea` is a closure. It has access to the imported `π` variable thanks to lexical scoping.

If we want to use `π` directly within the template, we must attach it to something that will be in scope for the template. Usually we just attach it to the component instance itself, as you have done.

```
import {π} from 'app/constants';

export class CommonNumericalStuffComponent {
  π = π;
}
```

`π` will never change. Putting it in a service is nonsense.

For such use cases, I think your "workaround", as repeated in the last example above, is actually the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

yes by declaring it as injectable constants.

```
@Injectable()
export class Numbers{

 public MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9999
}
```

inject it to the component constructor

```
constructor(private Number:Numbers){}
```

and then use it in your html as

```
<div (click)="lastCall(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)">click me</div>
```

Comment: Is that the smoothest way? My work-around creates a single extra line in code-behind. The approach you're suggesting creates a new file, a new class and an additional injection. I'm not questioning your input by any means. Just curious if that's the proper(est) way to do it.

Comment: yes. that is how hardcoded values should be used. assume if some days down the max value is to be revised to `9999` will you change in all files?

Comment: This will come in very handy when you need to mock the maximum safe integer when writing unit tests. A robust solution.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh, changing the value in each file is **not** a preferred solution (nor a solution I wanted to aim at, even though *Find-In-Files* should do pragmatically speaking). My issue with the solution you suggested's rather about the fact that `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is already well-defined and present so it seems unnecessary to redefine it. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry my comment was meant as sarcasm I guess that didn't come across. If something is truly a constant like max safe integer, then providing it with a service is ridiculous

Comment: @AluanHaddad Oh, it certainly did not come across. Most likely due to me being totally dense as a black hole (not enough sleep the last days + frustration over the stupid computer not doing what I want, hehe). I love sarcasm otherwise but got uncertain in regard to Angular if it, possibly, **could** be the way to go. Now, that it's said - how would you get to the true constancy of the `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`?

Comment: I added an answer